# React Native use multiple components without sharing state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm building a react native app and I'm trying to use multiple of the same component in a list. I have a component ListItem with its own state where it holds a name. Then I have a MyList component that uses map to render a bunch of ListItems.

I have some Async functions in the ListItem that pull images for that specific item, but I'm having problems with some sort of cross-contamination where pulling an image for one ListItem will change the images on some other ListItems? Not sure exactly how this is happening.

Is there a way to 'isolate' these components or reset the state so that they are independent of one another? In the constructor of each I have

```
class ListItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {STATE STUFF HERE}
         this._functionThatPullsAsyncImages(); //this places an image url into the state
    }
    render(){RENDER STUFF HERE}

    _functionThatPullsAsyncImages = async() => {
        this.setState({coverImage : await getPlaylistImageURL(this.props.playlistId)}) 
    }
```

Comment: Please try to add enough code to the question to reproduce the problem

Comment: I noticed in some examples that sometimes state is defined both before the constructor and then inside, does that change the operation of the component? Also, sorry for the short code, my codebase is really long and complicated and not really useful to look at in it's un-summarized form.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is setting a placeholder image and fire an async call to load the image in a life cycle method `componentDidMount()` instead of the constructor. Something like this:

```js
class ListItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {STATE STUFF HERE}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // 1. Set placeholder

        // 2. call async image loader
        this._functionThatPullsAsyncImages(); //this places an image url into the state
    }
    render(){RENDER STUFF HERE}

    _functionThatPullsAsyncImages = async() => {
        this.setState({coverImage : await getPlaylistImageURL(this.props.playlistId)}) 
    }
```

Comment: This is better style, and so I've update to code to reflect this change, but unfortunately it hasn't fixed my cross-contamination issue. The images can still mess with each other...

Comment: Could you provide some specifications on how the `state` is initialized and how `coverImage` is used in `render()`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thanks for the help, I figured this one out.

My results were actually getting cross-contaminated in the async function getPlaylistImageURL(). One of my variables that sets the id of the image to pull was not defined as a const, which was allowing different instances of the async function to overwrite it, feeding in wrong id's.

Once I fixed this everything worked out.